# Orkut application development

Tags: jquery, opensocial

I am new to orkut application development. I just came to know about jQuery and found it very interesting and useful. Is it possible to use jQuery with open-social to develop orkut applications? Please give me a link to some examples too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Google?

Yes, it is very much possible to use jQuery with Orkut's APIs. The Open Social framework allows you to log-in, create a session, access the user's data (with some restrictions) and so on. jQuery on the other hand provides a set of generic APIs for a HTML document handling. You may want to read the tutorials separately as also this ['Using jQuery with other libraries'](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

You may want to take a look at [opensocial-jquery](http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-jquery/).